# How to update existing records in SQL Server table with PySpark?

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks

There is a SQL Server table "update_records" and I am reading into dataframe DF1 and I want to update the null values in DF1 what ever present in DF2 as per the key value.

```
DF1=[("key1", NULL), ("key2", NULL), ("key3", NULL), ("key4", 204),("key5", 205)]
DF2=[("key1", 201), ("key2", 202), ("key3", 203)]
```

After updating DF1 with DF2 here

```
DF1=[("key1", 201), ("key2", 202), ("key3", 203), ("key4", 204),("key5", 205)]
```

When I am writing to the same SQL Server table "update_records" with below code, but it is not working as expected

```
DF1.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("dbtable", "update_records") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()
```

How to update the table without even loosing/duping the records. (Consider if the data was in Millions).
Please help I got stuck with this issue.

Here my problem is

- when I am using .mode("overwrite") it's erasing all the records in the table
- when I am using .mode("append") it's appending dupes to the existing table

I want to read the table and perform some operation and update the values back to the same table without touching the not null records by using pyspark azure databricks.

Comment: I think you need to think of some type of stage table to track the records and after this perform upsert operations into your SQL Server Database

Comment: you have to look into `merge` sql server command. I'm not going to write the code but the solution would be to write your updated row into a temp table in sql server and update your main table using sql command in sql server (not in spark), you can still do it from your data pipeline code

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
jdbcHostname = "dileepdbserver02.database.windows.net"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "db02"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};databaseName={jdbcDatabase}"
connectionProperties = {
    "user": "dilip",
    "password": "Welcome@1"
}
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Spark SQL Example") \
    .getOrCreate()
data1 = [("key1", None), ("key2", None), ("key3", None), ("key4", 204), ("key5", 205)]
data2 = [("key1", 201), ("key2", 202), ("key3", 203)]
columns = ["key", "value"]
DF1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, columns)
DF2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, columns)
DF1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
DF2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
updated_df = spark.sql("""
    SELECT df1.key, COALESCE(df2.value, df1.value) AS value
    FROM df1
    LEFT JOIN df2 ON df1.key = df2.key
""")
updated_df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", "update_records") \
    .option("user", connectionProperties["user"]) \
    .option("password", connectionProperties["password"]) \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()
```

[image]

[image]

- DataFrames, **DF1** and **DF2**, Doing a left join between them using the "**key**" column, and then uses `COALESCE` to update the "**value**" column in **DF1** with values from **DF2** where they exist.

It writes the updated DataFrame (updated_df) back to the "**update_records**" table in SQL Server using `.mode("overwrite")`, which will replace the existing data in the table.

Comment: What if we only need to update 1 million rows and we have 100 million rows in the table and this will update all the rows in that table.